# Select distinct pairs from a MySQL table data in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am writing a logistics application that tracks various routes, I want to write code that can find all the routes in the system.

For example in the following database:

```
From    |      To | Time
------------------------
Seattle | Chicago | 12PM
Chicago | Seattle | 9 AM
Seattle | Chicago | 2PM
Chicago | Houston | 3PM
```

The result should be:

```
From    |      To
-----------------
Seattle | Chicago
Chicago | Houston
```

Basically, the direction doesn't matter, only the pairs do.

I tried using join statements by using djangos raw() function but this prints out all the routes multiplied by the number of times that pair appears, so in the above example it would print out the 1st, 2nd and 3rd record 3 times each as well as the last record.

```
fls = Route.objects.raw('SELECT * '
                         'FROM manager_route f1, flights_flight f2 '
'WHERE (f1.origin_id = f2.destination_id AND f1.destination_id = f2.origin_id)'
'OR (f1.origin_id = f2.origin_id AND f1.destination_id = f2.destination_id)')
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to use `raw()`? Can't you use other Django models query functions?

Comment: No, I just need a way to interact with it in django, from what I could find there is no function that does what I want in django however

Comment: Did the `SELECT DISTINCT ...` can help you?

Comment: That only selects distinct cities and not pairs, also doesnt provide a reference to the record that django needs for me to interact with the RawQuery object. For now I am using the `GROUP BY` statement but it cares about directionality and therefore returns both Seattle -> Chicago and Chicago -> Seattle in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while I was able to find a solution:

```
fls = Route.objects.raw(
      'SELECT f1.* '
      'FROM manager_route f1 '
      'JOIN manager_route f2 '
      'ON f1.origin_id = f2.destination_id '
      'AND f1.destination_id = f2.origin_id '
      'AND f1.origin_id > f2.origin_id '
      'GROUP BY f1.origin_id, f1.destination_id'
)
```

Will select distinct city pairs (granted not in any sorted fashion so far as I can tell), GROUP BY is needed to prevent it printing each entry several times (otherwise it prints it the number of times that the pair appears)