# SQL select row containing value from intersect with other row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table which compares sports result like this:

```
Home    Away    Win
--------------------
A       C       A
C       B       B
A       D       D
C       D       C
```

I am trying to compare team A and team B, I know they haven't played each 
other. I need to find if there is a team they have both played and if they is one return that. I don't know which team played at home or away.

In this case both A and B played team C so I would need the first two rows.
Is there a way to do this with SQL?

Edit:
The result I want from this is:

```
Home    Away    Win
--------------------
A       C       A
C       B       B
```

If there are no shared teams nothing should be returned.

```
Home    Away    Win
--------------------
A       C       A
E       B       B
A       D       D
C       D       C
```

In this case A and B have no shared teams so nothing should be returned.

```
Home    Away    Win
--------------------
```

if there are multiple shared teams all the shared teams should be returned.

```
Home    Away    Win
--------------------
A       C       A
C       B       B
A       D       D
B       D       B
E       A       A
```

In this case both C and D are shared so they should both be returned.

```
Home    Away    Win
--------------------
A       C       A
C       B       B
A       D       D
B       D       C
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What results do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to find "A  C  A" and "C  B  B" because team A and team B have both played team C. If team B had played team D I would want that result too.

Comment: . . Edit your question and show the results that you want.  The question is unclear.  Also address issues about what happens if there is more than one "third" team or no "third" teams.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited the question to add examples, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can do it with a subquery that uses `intersect` to get all the teams that both 'A' and 'B' have played against:

```
select * from tablename 
where 
    (home in ('A', 'B') or away in ('A', 'B'))
    and 
    case when home in ('A', 'B') then away else home end in (
      select case when home = 'A' then away else home end team 
      from tablename where home = 'A' or away = 'A'
      intersect  
      select case when home = 'B' then away else home end team 
      from tablename where home = 'B' or away = 'B'
    )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8gqo8Vm6uWecB5HihbW8Lb/0)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue earlier, here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986459/1830386

If you dont want it to group, just remove the GROUP BY statement in the end of the query and you should be good